# NAV Submenu Hover on Touch screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, drop-down-menu

```
<li>
    <a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a>
    <div class="submenu">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <h2>ABOUT US</h2>
            <img src="images/sub-menu-img-about.jpg" alt="img"></div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

On touch screen Hover will not work because, I have linked the main nav to a page. So onclick from touch screen device it will redirects, but I need to show submenu . Please help me to sort with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have HTML like this:

```
<a href="#">Do Something</a>
```

You would do something like this with jQuery:

```
$("a").on('click', function( event ) {

  // preventDefault prevents your site from navigating away
  event.preventDefault(); 

  // your code here to show submenu or change classnames
  alert('prevented navigation');
});
```

Comment: Hi Randi, Thanks for your reply..

My HTML is like

<a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a>

I have a link on the About Us Main menu..also on hover it will show the submenu on desktop and Laptops, But in Touch devices, hover will not work..on click from touch screens it will open the about us page. instead of that I need to show the Submenu without redirecting abou page.